# How to configure Spring OAuth2 in JHipster for stateless authentication against GitLab?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, gitlab, jhipster, stateless

I have set up an OAuth2-based installation (spring-security-oauth2-core 5.2.4) of JHipster (3.9.0) against a gitlab repository. Mainly following https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2 but using gitlab instead of keycloak.

This is an excerpt from the application.yml:

```yaml
    spring: ...
     security:
      oauth2:
       client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://gitlab.mysite.com
         registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: 1234123412322312312312312312321312321312
            client-secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Indeed the oauth2-authentication works well, until the session internally expires. When the client then returns the jsession-Id cookie, the underlying undertow-infrastructure throws a  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session is invalid`.

It seems that `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.saveAuthorizationRequest` stores the authorizationRequest in the user session not caring about session management configuration: (see last line below)

```java
        @Override
    public void saveAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response) {
        Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(response, "response cannot be null");
        if (authorizationRequest == null) {
            this.removeAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
            return;
        }
        String state = authorizationRequest.getState();
        Assert.hasText(state, "authorizationRequest.state cannot be empty");
        Map<String, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> authorizationRequests = this.getAuthorizationRequests(request);
        authorizationRequests.put(state, authorizationRequest);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName, authorizationRequests);
    }
```

This approach seems to contradict the stateless JWT-based authentication approach of JHipster (see e.g. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8627).
Anyway the spring2 OAuth2 management seems to counterfeit classical load balancing approaches.

Is there a way to configure OAuth2 management in spring to work stateless with GitLab?